# Disable Routing in TYPO3 9

Tags: url, typo3, typo3-9.x

I have 3 Sites on a development server in one TYPO3 Instance with one domain. No option to create another subdoamin. Routing doesnt work because some of the pages have the same names. For now I would like to simply disable routing and work with page IDs but I can not find a setting for this.

So - how can I disable routing in TYPO3 9?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not defining the sites with a different base below the same domain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no option to disable routing. You should think about adding an entry to your `etc/hosts` file to add a custom domain and use that one.

Comment: working without routing must be possible as I have an 9 installation (with just one domain) where I have no routing at all. all links just use `id`parameter. this is a 'fresh' update from 8 and until now I had no time to care about routing, so I did not configured anything yet.

Comment: this might be the case if no site configuration is yet created but this is just a fallback and not the way to go. with 10 all fallbacks like e.g sysdomains are removed and your way is not possible anymore