# Howto temporary disable speaking url for logged in frontend users?

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, typo3-10.x

Is it possible to disable the speaking urls for logged in frontend users in TYPO3 9 or 10? With `ext:realUrl` this was easily possible with the following typoscript:

```
[loginUser = *]
    config.tx_realurl_enable = 0
[global]
```

Is there something like that in TYPO3 9 or 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to turn off routing in TYPO3 v9 or v10.
See here: [Disable Routing in TYPO3 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56342016/disable-routing-in-typo3-9)