# TYPO3 v. 10.4 Turn off the URL Rewriting

Tags: url-rewriting, typo3, typo3-10.x

The version 10.4 generates all URLs for any page and sometimes it produces wrong language links.
In order to check if it is the URI builder which causes the erroneous links I'd like to turn the speaking URLs off.

How can the URL builder be turned off in version 10.4? Is it possible at all?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable Routing in TYPO3 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56342016/disable-routing-in-typo3-9)

Comment: I also checked by disabling .htaccess, although not working. It will always adds slug by default. May be you can edit page slug where wrong language links.

Answer (score 1):

Since ver.: `9.*` it's almost impossible, since ver.: `10.*` is quite impossible.

See also: [Disable Routing in TYPO3 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56342016/disable-routing-in-typo3-9)